# How do I add lines of text in between bootstrap table rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tablelayout

I have been trying to create a table in bootstrap with lines of text in between rows, to delineate different groups in a table without having to duplicate the header and making multiple tables. Here is an example of what I have tried to do.

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        A sub-header introducing a different group of data.
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>

   <h3>Another sub-header introducing a different group of data</h3>

  <table class='table'>
    <!-- Header is omitted -->

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Making a new table row and making the sub-header the first and only column of a row looks bad because text is compressed into this single column. I also tried to make a new table and just omit the header, replacing this with a header tag placed between the two tables. This resulted in the misalignment of all proceeding rows, since they had no header to align themselves to. All I want is a line of text I can insert between rows of a table without disturbing the structure of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 columns in the row above, you need to have a colspan property:
    
      
        A sub-header introducing a different group of data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same table, and use colspan to take several cases. `<td colspan="2">blabla</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML5 spec example for delineate different rows, via combining the use of `<tbody>`, `<th scope="rowgroup">`, `<th scope="row">`:

```
<table>
<caption>Measurement of legs and tails in Cats and English speakers</caption>
<thead>
<tr> <th> ID <th> Measurement <th> Average <th> Maximum
<tbody>
<tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> Cats <td> <td>
<tr> <td> 93 <th scope=row> Legs <td> 3.5 <td> 4
<tr> <td> 10 <th scope=row> Tails <td> 1 <td> 1
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> English speakers <td> <td>
<tr> <td> 32 <th scope=row> Legs <td> 2.67 <td> 4
<tr> <td> 35 <th scope=row> Tails <td> 0.33 <td> 1
</tbody>
</table>
```

Source: HTML5 spec, [4.9.10 The th element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element)